# Spring Cloud Config Server Configurations

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I am using Spring Cloud Config Server as an Externalized Configuration, but Spring Cloud Config Server itself is a microservice that needs some configs like GIT URL, username, and password... From where it needs to get the configurations, arent we having an infinite loop problem ?

Comment: You will need to put static information in some place if you want everything to run on its own. If you want to pass everything dynamically like a username, you can leverage CI/CD pipelines and provide the information at deployment time. But that will delay your auto-deployment, awaiting manual intervention.

Comment: I would not like to have a manual intervention, for that, I just need to have another config source.
I have some dynamic configurations and therefore decided to use externalized configuration. Spring gives me that opportunity. It turns out that I need to have 2 configuration sources, one maintained by spring-cloud-config-server and one for spring-cloud-config-server configurations and also for all clients to configure the server-host.